# Возникает ошибка при создании слушателя для кнопки

Tags: java, android, listener

Добавил в метод onCreate слушатель для кнопки:

```
mCheatButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Start CheatActivity
    }
});
```

Появилась ошибка:

[image]

Несколько раз проверял код слушателя, вроде всё правильно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать

Comment: кнопка не создается. Проверьте правильность id и его наличие в xml

Comment: Дело не в слушателе, а в том что в разметке, которую вы установили в `setContentView(...)` не найдена кнопка с `id` `cheat_button` (`findViewById(R.id.cheat_button)` вернул `null`). Проверьте ту ли разметку вы ставите и что нужная кнопка именно в ней, а не какой-то другой.

Comment: добавьте текст ошибки текстом а не картинкой

Comment: Всем спасибо!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас nullPointerException. Метод findViewById вернул null, сам слушатель роли не играет. В разметке нет вьюшки с указанным id

Comment: Большое спасибо!)